# Upsampling with FIR filter causing discontinuity at start of new buffer

Tags: filter-design, convolution, lowpass-filter, c++, finite-impulse-response

I have implemented an oversampling algorithm for an audio signal in C++ which is producing a distortion of the signal at the start of a buffer. The algorithm is wrapped in a class with methods for up and down sampling by a factor of 4, with a 256 tap linear phase FIR filter performing the "interpolation" of the upsampled signal. The distortion occurs after convolving the input signal with the filter coefficients so I think that is the source of the problem.

Here is the function I am using to apply the upsampling (where the distortion is first noticed):

```
// Upsample a signal four times
std::vector<double> oversample::upsample4x(double* inBuffer, size_t inLength)
{
    // Output length is 4 times the length of the input
    size_t outLength = 4*inLength;

    // Create vectors for the upsampled signal, pre and post filtering.
    std::vector<double> upSampled(outLength);
    std::vector<double> upFiltered(outLength);

    // Pad the signal with zeros
    for(size_t i=0; i<inLength; i++)
    {
        size_t j = i*4;
        upSampled[j] = inBuffer[i];
        upSampled[j+1] = 0;
        upSampled[j+2] = 0;
        upSampled[j+3] = 0;
    }

    // Use FIR filter to remove aliased images
    // accumulator for each sample
    double acc;
    for(size_t k=0; k<outLength; k++)
    {
        // Put the current sample into the buffer.
        upHistory[upIndex] = upSampled[k];

        // Create a local copy of the current index for calculating the output.
        size_t outIndex = upIndex;

        // Zero the accumulator.
        acc = 0;

        // For the zero-indexed array of length QTAPS (length of FIR+1).
        for(size_t i=0; i<QTAPS; i++)
        {
            // Convolve the buffer with the filter.
            acc += upHistory[outIndex] * quarterTaps[i];

            // If the index is above zero, decrement, otherwise set it to the filter length.
            outIndex = (outIndex > 0) ? --outIndex : QTAPS;
        }
        // Assign accumulator to the output vector.
        upFiltered[k] = 2*acc;

        // Check to see if we have reached the end of buffer.
        upIndex = (upIndex < QTAPS) ? ++upIndex : 0;
    }

    // Return the upsampled and filtered signal.
    return upFiltered;
}
```

The `size_t upIndex` is a member of th class `oversample` as well as the buffer `upHistory` which is the past signal used for the convolution. The algorithm is implemented as a ring buffer. `QTAPS` is the number of taps used for the filter (at a quarter of the sampling rate hence qtaps).

An illustration of the problem can be seen in this MATLAB figure:

[image: Upsampled Signal]

The input signal is 1500 samples long (so upsampled is 6000), after which I put the same signal through again. The real problem with this is that when I implement it for audio it gives an audible buzz every buffer, making the audio unusable. I've looked through the algorithm too many times and can no longer see any issues, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT*: There was a discontinuity in the sine wave which is causing the visible distortion in the previous figure. This new figure illustrates a zoomed time domain shot of a guitar chord, where there are two very clear discontinuities which were not present in the original signal.

[image: Up and downsampled signal]

There are 30 samples between each peak, and the two peaks are periodic with a period of the length of the filter. I think the two peaks are caused by the two convolution processes from the up and down sampling (same filter, same code, just one pads and one decimates). I still can't figure out where this jump is coming from.

Comment: have you checked the initial conditions ? block based audio processing requires you to supply correct initial conditions at the beginning of every frame.

Comment: I presume this is the problem but I can't see it anywhere. The variables `upIndex` and `upHistory` are persistent as they are members of the class.

Comment: I've looked at your code... it seems to me that at the **beginning** of the **convolution** computation by **flip&drag** method, where the input signal portion is shorter than the filter length, is causing the problem... Those index variables are out of yoru control... That's all I can say without further information. You better write your own method. it will be a mere copy of the above code with a few lines of added.

Comment: The signal I am using is actually discontinuous, which is causing this visibile glitch, I will edit the question to note this, but leave it for posterity. The audible problem is still present, and is dependent upon amplitude and sounds like a buzz that fades in and out. I will try to post a better description soon.

Comment: The matlab figure does not show up in my browser ?

Comment: Do either of them show up? Does it provide a link to the imgur URL at least?

Comment: All figures show up for me.

Comment: I'm wondering about the line `outIndex = (outIndex > 0) ? --outIndex : QTAPS;`  Should `outIndex` really ever by set to `QTAPS`? Shouldn't that be `QTAPS-1`?

Comment: @PeterK. The same line I'm suspecting of

Comment: That was it, two off-by-one errors in two locations (also for the upIndex condition). Thanks for your time @PeterK.

Comment: No problem!  Still going to leave this closed. It's not really a good fit here.